# Custom SSIS Task Failing To Load. How Do I Troubleshoot?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I built a custom SSIS task that wraps an old program to allow it being called automatically.

Recently, I've been having problems with the task ! It seems that when scheduled 
to automatically run, the custom task is failing validation with the message:

"Task failed to load"

My task's `Execute` method looks something like this:

```
Public Overrides Function Execute(connections As Connections, 
variableDispenser As VariableDispenser, componentEvents As 
IDTSComponentEvents, log As IDTSLogging, transaction As Object) 
As DTSExecResult

        Dim objApp = CreateObject("MyProgram")

        Try
            objApp.ExecuteSomeStuff()
        Finally
            objApp.Exit()
        End Try

        Return DTSExecResult.Success

    End Function
```

I also implemented a custom UI, with a custom icon

Any reason why this might be happening? What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about this ? Code ? Tables ? anything ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I have updated the task with more info. It's a very simple task. If you need more, let me know :)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you. I only know basic SSIS, and certainly not enough to make my own custom components. I envy you. You might have to wait for a while over here. I suggest that you try the MSDN forums as well. That is the to go place for such esoteric MS tools. T-SQL gets quick replies here though.

Comment: Have you tried running the jobstep in 32bit?
And does the user that runs the jobstep has sufficient rights?

Comment: Did you deploy this dll to your SQL Server location? If you havent added this to the global cache, you wont be able to use it. There are some steps that you will need to finish before you can use your custom component.

Comment: @Joost Running in 32-bit mode didn't seem to solve the problem. As for permissions, do you know which permissions might be getting in the way?

Comment: @rvphx We have added it to the GAC, yes. There was a point where this task was working, but our methods for executing SSIS packages have evolved significantly over the last bit

Comment: Well, its much tougher to debug because there are really no code step ins or stuff (unless you want to throw in a couple of message boxes in the code). If its not loading, my guess is that the location where the package is at does not have the binary for the script task.

Comment: @rvphx It's not a script task, it's a custom task. Deriving from DtsTask. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: Slip of characters. I meant custom task. Can you execute the same package through BIDS? And does it work then? Is the job scheduled on the same machine as the package was developed on? Was this running before and suddenly started having problems?

Comment: @rvphx Executes through BIDS just fine. Scheduling machine doesn't have dev tools on it, and isn't the same machine. Yes, it was running fine at one point and now it just... doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your scheduling machine needs to have the same .net framework that was used to develop the custom task. Apart from that, you will need to follow the same steps(that you took on the BIDS/working machine) to make the task workable/available to the package.

In case, this was deployed to the other machine and was working fine, you will need to trace any software patches that were applied to it. Sometimes, the .net framework gets updated or has some other change that messes up the custom task.

Comment: .NET frameworks versions are identical, I deployed the DLL to the same folders on both machines (GAC and Tasks folder). Off the top of your head, do you know of any problematic software I should look for?